# Gnome animations gone after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 18.04, animations

All animations were working in 17.10 before upgrading.  Afterward, no animations.

The "Animations" toggle in `tweaks` is "On".  I've confirmed that using the dconf editor.  I tried toggling it, but all animations seem to be off either way, including the dock hiding, which I turned on.  When a window approachs the dock, it simply vanishes as if the animations were off.

I checked `journalctl -b0` for any clues but there's no warnings, failures, etc.

I did try a Wayland session for kicks but that completely failed.  Related?

Anyway, at least everything else in the Xorg session appears to be working just fine.  It's not a big deal.  But I'm mystified.

Any ideas?

---

**Solution**

Okay, I figured this out.   The artful installer left `nux-tools`, left over from unity, in a half-installed state but did purge it. This left a start up script in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` which interfered with the gnome-session in bionic. Purged that and the problem was gone.

So this is a dependency bug in the `nux-tools` package (or perhaps some mistakenly identified changed file which the package partly installed and turned into evil cruft). Sigh. Took me a long time to find this.

May this report help somebody else.  **Be careful to remove all of `nux-tools` which switching over from Unity.**

Comment: How did you figure out which script it was? I have a dozen..

Comment: I skimmed through them.  Most of them are not that long.  Anyway, the one you need to worry about  is `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/50_check_unity_support`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing and using vanilla-gnome-desktop on my ubuntu 18.04